# Updating Class Variables While Using Sprite Groups

Tags: python, function, class, pygame, sprite

Ill show you my code first(Outside of main loop):

```
START_BAT_COUNT = 10
BAT_IMAGE_PATH = os.path.join( 'Sprites', 'Bat_enemy', 'Bat-1.png' )

bat_image = pygame.image.load(BAT_IMAGE_PATH).convert_alpha()
bat_image = pygame.transform.scale(bat_image, (80, 70))


class Bat(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, bat_x, bat_y, bat_image, bat_health, bat_immune):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.bat_health = bat_health
        self.bat_immune = bat_immune
        self.image = bat_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.rect.topleft = (bat_x, bat_y)
        self.bat_x = bat_x
        self.bat_y = bat_y
    def update(self):
        self.bat_x += 500

all_bats = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(START_BAT_COUNT):
    bat_x = (random.randint(0, 500))
    bat_y = (random.randint(0, 500))
    bat_health = 5
    bat_immune = False

    new_bat = Bat(bat_x, bat_y, bat_image, bat_health, bat_immune)
    all_bats.add(new_bat)
```

Inside main loop:

```
all_bats.update()
all_bats.draw(display)
```

In update() I increase the value of bat_x by 500 every time the code is read, and I know the value of bat_x increases as I have tested this by printing the values of bat_x and watching them increase. My question is, is there a way to increase bat_x, and have that actually move my bat? As of now, the variable increases but the bat doesn't move. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What are the dimensions of your display? If you are moving the bat 500 pixels in the x direction then it will immediately fly off the screen once it starts moving. Also, your bat might not be moving because you didn't update the position of its rectangle.

In the lines

```
    def update(self):
        self.bat_x += 500
```

try

```
    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(500, 0)
```

where `move_ip` moves the rectangle in-place and will increase the bat's x coordinate by 500 each time it updates.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks. Also, the moving 500 pixels was just to test whether the bats actually moved so I chose a random number.

Comment: @Owen Penn Happy to help. I'm am editing my answer to include y=0 movement in `move_ip` since you need to include both an x and y value.